# Partitioning my hard disk keeping everything and saving 20GB for Ubuntu:Possible?

Tags: 12.04

I know that if I want to use Ubuntu aside Windows 7, I'll have to partition the drives, but I don't actually know about partitioning. This is very new. I want to ask something. How should I partition my drives?

I currently have this sort of configuration:[image]

What I want to do:
1. No changes to /dev/sda3 (ANKITA) (That's somebody else's)
2. Utilize 5 GB from /dev/sda2 and 15 GB from /dev/sda4 and that unallocated space
3. So, I want to use 20 GB to get some Ubuntu experience.

How to do this? What are the possible dangerous outcomes?
(I'm sick of using Ubuntu from LIVECD)
Thanks a lot.
UPDATE:
I now have a better situation. I've formatted sda3 and now I want to install Ubuntu inside that drive. How do I proceed?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gparted always involves the possibility of losing all the data on that drive or partition. You wont harm the hardware of the drive with standard operations though. You should always back up your data before using Gparted

With Gparted you can just click the move/resize button with the partition you want selected. Then modify the before and after spaces next to the partition.

If it were me doing this, I would backup the partitions that you want to modify. Then format them and then just install everything from scratch. Resizing partitions is more complicated than its worth in my opinion.

Comment: that's alright, but how exactly do I partition the thing(the new map say 100 MB for Windows, 25 GB for C:/ and so on) so that I have 20 GB for Ubuntu? I mean since 4 primary partitions already exist, is this possible?

Comment: GPT (GUID Partition Table) supports up to 128 primary partitions, so if your system supports that it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Splinter701 gave a pretty good answer, keep his'/hers in mind. I'm gonna try to be a bit more specific to your situation.*

If you resize sda2 and sda4 you end up with two unallocated spaces, so you have to move sda3 to get one unallocated space were you can create a new partition. The problem is that this involves a lot of resizing and moving of partitions and as Splinter701 suggested it is better to recreate them.

A good rule of thump is **to avoid resizing and/or moving of partitions**, since this takes a long time and can cause problems and frustration.

- If there is nothing important on a partition, just remove it and make
  a new one.
- If you do have important stuff on the partition, make
  sure to make a backup before resizing. (Always backup before changing
  your partition table)
- And now you have a backup there is no reason
  to not recreate your partition...

---

**Primary partitions, extended partitions, and logical partitions**

As you mentioned, you already have four primary partitions and can't create a fifth. To solve this, delete one partition (lets say sda4) and create an extended partition in the unallocated space that you just created. Inside this extended partition you can recreate sda4 and make any other partition you need (as logical partitions).

If you're confused by the words 'primary' 'extended' and 'logical' you should read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/337146/what-are-the-differences-between-primary-and-logical-partition) question about the subject. It has some pretty good answers.
.

Comment: I just formatted sda3 on the person's permission. Is there any way I can install Ubuntu on it? The file system is NTFS.

Comment: You can't install ubuntu on NTFS, this has to be EXT4. You also need a swap partition. Provided that you leave sda1, 2 an 4 unchanged, you now have 5 partitions, so you need an extended partition as explained above. All of this can be done during the installation.

Comment: Successfully installed Ubuntu(but without swap), working fine and well.